# Get the value of ANTD Datepicker and show in Alert

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am new in React and I want creating antd DatePicker, it will pop up when i click on button click so it don't have the Input. I want to show the value of Datepicker in alert message. How can do this?

Here my Datepicker code

```
                                <DatePicker 
                                    id='date_p'
                                    format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
                                    disabledDate={disabledDate}
                                    disabledTime={disabledDateTime}
                                    showTime={{ defaultValue: moment('00:00', 'HH:mm'), format: 'HH:mm' }}  
                                    open={datePickerOpen}
                                    onOk={onConfirm}
                                    onChange = {onSelectDate}
                                    suffixIcon
                                    />
```

Here my alert code

```
<Alert message='You message will be send at' type="info" showIcon closable onClose={onClose}/>
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSelectDate` function accepts two arguments. The first is the date in moment format and the second is the date in string format. You can save it on the local state and display it in an alert message something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-18-3-forked-rvdj1?file=/index.js)

Comment: Thank you it working but when i add `message={'You message will be send at' + {date}}` , the date will become [Object object], is there any solution for this?

Comment: I assume you are using date in moment format. replace with  `message={'You message will be send at' + {moment().format(date)}}`